# jsf viewParam always null

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to use jsf viewParam to grab a parameter say "paramName" before the view is render and have it check if it is valid. I am using this for a token system for users to reset there passwords. There is a base template with corresponding content, footer, and header templatees. I have a userBean which is a session bean and has the following code

```
private String paramName; // +getter+setter

public void check() {

    System.out.print(paramName);

}
/**
 * @return the paramName
 */
public String getParamName() {
    return paramName;
}

/**
 * @param paramName the paramName to set
 */
public void setParamName(String paramName) {
    this.paramName = paramName;
}
```

base.xhtml template

```
  <h:body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <f:view>
                         <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
                    <!-- Header Begin -->
                    <ui:insert name="header">
                        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/header.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
```

resetPassword.xhtml

```
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/base.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="title">Recover your username</ui:define>
            <ui:define name="metadata">
                <f:metadata>
                    <f:viewParam id="paramName" name="paramName" value="#{userBean.paramName}" required="true" />
                    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{userBean.check}" />
                </f:metadata>
            </ui:define>

            <!-- Defines main content (not including header, footer, or menu) -->
            <ui:define name="content">

            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I have read / done research online and followed tutorials, why is my paramName always null?

Comment: I am starting to wonder if it matters that I am using a session bean vs. a view scoped bean from the articles i am reading: http://jdevelopment.nl/stateless-stateful-jsf-view-parameters/

Comment: what JSF version are you using ?

Comment: Try this with a `@ViewScoped` bean and inform us about your results.

Comment: jsf 2.1 and changing to @viewScope still results in null values